# Can't install react-router-dom in command prompt

Tags: reactjs

While installing `react-router-dom` in the command prompt the following output is shown which is given in the following screenshot. 
 And in my `package.json` file, I could not find `react-router-dom`. Thanks in advance.
 [image: Image Here]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy/paste the output here directly rather than posting a screenshot. Many people visit this site on mobile and screenshots are difficult to read on devices with small screen sizes.

Comment: the error looks very clear. the folder from where you are trying to install does not contain a `package.json` file. what is the `pwd` of the package.json file you are looking at?

Comment: @azium Note that is a warning, not an error.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the screenshot you provided, react-router-dom installed successfully. Please provide additional information showing an error or other evidence that it isn't installed.

Comment: If you are in the root of your project, then make sure you have ran the command `npm init`

Comment: per your screenshot, you are trying to install react router to your Windows `User` folder directly, not a subfolder (containing a project) as one would expect. This would explain why you have `no package.json file` warning errors, and whatever the path is to your project is, I bet it's not `C:\Users\Abdullah` - so in short, you need to navigate your command prompt to the correct path of your project, then run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

You must be inside a generated project directory (with package.json file witch is the file that contains the dependencies of your project) to run this command.